# Pointer issue, assignment

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to assign a value to variable root for my function, doesn't seem to be working. I don't understand the issue.

hw7.c:155:7: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  root = Load(&fp, size);

this code creates a doubly linked list and then adds to it in a insertion sort and then also deletes

The issue i am getting is located in main at this line 
root = Load(&fp, size);

```
struct node * LOAD(FILE *stream, int size){
     int x;
     char *tempLine = NULL;
     size_t length = 0;
     const char delim[] = " ";
     char *token;
     char *name;
     char *ADCheck;
     struct node *root;

     rewind(stream);


     for(x = 0; x < size; x++){
          getline(&tempLine, &length, stream);
          token = strtok(tempLine, delim);
          name = token;
          token = strtok(NULL, delim);   
          ADCheck = token;   

          if(( strcasecmp(ADCheck, "a") == 0) ) {

               root = insertNode(root, name);
          }else{
               root = delete(root, name);
          } 
          length = 0;
          tempLine = NULL;
     }
     free(tempLine);
     return root;
}


int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    int size;
    struct node *root;

    root = NULL;

    fp = fopen("hw7.data", "r");

    size = SCAN(&fp);

    root = LOAD(&fp, size);

    Free(root);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I bet that you think `}else{if(((strcmp(currName, name) < 0) && (curr == root))){` this looks simpler or more readable, well it doesn't, it looks terrible and confusing!!!

Comment: Please edit your question to contain a [mcve]. Also, please learn to use whitespace judiciously; a decent amount of your code is difficult to read because you don't.

Comment: `if((strcasecmp(ADCheck, "a") == 0)){` maybe --> `if((strcasecmp(ADCheck, "a\n") == 0)){`

Comment: `root = Load(&fp, size);` --> `root = LOAD(fp, size);`

Comment: that causes the same error for  root = Load(fp, size);

Comment: `tempLine = NULL;` occurs memory leak --> `free(tempLine); tempLine = NULL;`

Comment: okay, please give descriptions of why i should do these things

Comment: `Load` is typo as `LOAD`.

Comment: Awesome, Thank you!

Comment: You didn't even copy **all** the warnings, or they weren't enabled - there probably should be a warning about implicit declaration of `Load`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are two mistakes.  As so often happens, one masks the other.

```
struct node * LOAD(FILE *stream, int size){
```

That defines `LOAD`, all upper case.  When you try to call it,

```
root = Load(&fp, size);
```

you use `Load`, which is undeclared.  Because it's undeclared, the C compiler assumes it returns `int`.  Because `root` is defined as a pointer, you get the *int-assigned-to-pointer* warning.

After you fix that, you'll get a different error.  The first parameter to `LOAD` (which you'll rename `Load`) is `FILE *`.  Your variable `fp` is a `FILE *`, but you're passing the address, `&fp`, which is `FILE **`.  You'll get a type error because of that.

If you have a pointer, pass the pointer.  It's a value, like any other; pass it as one.  Don't pass the pointer's address to a function unless you want the function to change where the pointer points.

Comment: @JeffreyHennen You should mark this answer as accepted by clicking the check mark if it solved your problem.